# R gsub increment in each new line

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a text file that has say 10 lines. I need to append "n: " and increment value in each line using gsub. I'm using R.

Here's what I've tried.

```
tst <- readLines("test.json")
fix <- gsub("*}$", paste0(",\"n\":\"",1:10,"\"}"), tst)
```

I know what's the issue with this one. It's searching for the pattern and adding n:1 for each one, but there's only one pattern that it matches per line, hence no increment. It's producing the following, for example. Please notice the value of `n`.

Please notice that the text is in json format as stated in EDIT.

Now, let's assume a = the json text in the first line, b is the json format in the second line, the above gsub gave me the following output.

```
a, n:1
b, n:1
c, n:1 ....
```

What I need is:

```
a, n:1
b, n:2
c, n:3
... 
and so on..
```

How can I do this?

EDIT:

```
tst <- "{\"text\":\"Call the first precinct at 212-334-0611 and demand they hurry up and clear out the riff-raff #OWS\",\"location\":{\"lng\":-77.047203,\"lat\":39.4170472},\"geoflag\":false,\"screen_name_lower\":3696254146976399714,\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[{\"text\":\"#ows\"}],\"user_mentions\":[{\"screen_name\":\"5703714229808319021\"}]},\"timestamp\":1321340409000,\"id\":136337675450978305,\"source\":\"<a href=http://www.hootsuite.com rel=nofollow>HootSuite<\\/a>\",\"user\":{\"location\":\"WY and Washington DC\",\"screen_name\":3696254146976399714}}"
```

Edit 2:

Here's the actual tweet I have. I've only pasted 6 tweets.

```
{"text":"RT @2141912560879618632: Impeach Scalia and Thomas.  Clarence Thomas also a tax fraud.  #p2 http://t.co/SuzLE7kZ","location":{"lng":0,"lat":0},"geoflag":false,"screen_name_lower":8344340767467600327,"entities":{"urls":[{"expanded_url":"http://www.latimes.com/news/politics/la-pn-scalia-thomas-20111114","url":"http://www.latimes.com/news/politics/la-pn-scalia-thomas-20111114"}],"hashtags":[{"text":"#p2"}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"2141912560879618632"}]},"timestamp":1321340401000,"id":136337643519737856,"source":"<a href=http://ubersocial.com rel=nofollow>UberSocial for BlackBerry<\/a>","user":{"location":"wrong place at the wrong time","screen_name":8344340767467600327}}
{"text":"RT @6822250609460363149: Main Media Helicopters blocked from roads transit and airspace in NY. #ows","location":{"lng":-80.0110840074,"lat":40.4230666861},"geoflag":false,"screen_name_lower":3864938046499739811,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"#ows"}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":5703714229808319021}]},"timestamp":1321340402000,"id":136337644983566337,"source":"<a href=http://www.tweetdeck.com rel=nofollow>TweetDeck<\/a>","user":{"location":"Southern California","screen_name":3864938046499739811}}
{"text":"RT @4872494631597194689: A handful of protesters seem to be holding their ground in the middle of of the square, where the food tent is. #OWS","location":{"lng":-75.6681744492,"lat":42.9684876327},"geoflag":false,"screen_name_lower":3155607190500421639,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"#ows"}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"5703714229808319021"}]},"timestamp":1321340402000,"id":136337647592415232,"source":"<a href=http://twitter.com/#!/download/iphone rel=nofollow>Twitter for iPhone<\/a>","user":{"location":"New York","screen_name":3155607190500421639}}
{"text":"RT @5710636393838980539: Photo of Long Range Acoustic Device (LRAD) being staged near Zucotti Park http://t.co/ecKuyTno #OccupyWallSt #OccupyB ...","location":{"lng":0,"lat":0},"geoflag":false,"screen_name_lower":81153019260783000,"entities":{"urls":[{"expanded_url":"http://twitpic.com/7eebr3","url":"http://twitpic.com/7eebr3"}],"hashtags":[{"text":"#occupywallst"},{"text":"#occupyboston"}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"5703714229808319021"}]},"timestamp":1321340403000,"id":136337651665076225,"source":"<a href=http://www.tweetdeck.com rel=nofollow>TweetDeck<\/a>","user":{"location":"null","screen_name":81153019260783000}}
{"text":"RT @8527126922837269423: Here's the link that works to watch the livestream of the NYC police raid of #ows: http://t.co/S71XWGNL","location":{"lng":0,"lat":0},"geoflag":false,"screen_name_lower":171283756943800599,"entities":{"urls":[{"expanded_url":"http://bit.ly/v1TyPW","url":"http://bit.ly/v1TyPW"}],"hashtags":[{"text":"#ows"}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"5703714229808319021"}]},"timestamp":1321340404000,"id":136337656387866624,"source":"web","user":{"location":"flipadelphia","screen_name":171283756943800599}}
{"text":"RT @7526888406962725238: The police have blocked all entrances. They are not allowing press in. #ows","location":{"lng":9.6542972,"lat":45.3547433},"geoflag":false,"screen_name_lower":8941040531398533941,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"#ows"}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"5703714229808319021"}]},"timestamp":1321340405000,"id":136337660120805376,"source":"web","user":{"location":"NYC","screen_name":8941040531398533941}}
```

If you save these json in a file, and read it using readLines in R, then apply the above function, then it'll make sense to you, hopefully, that it appends (as per GSee) n:1 at the end of each json, but doesn't increament the value of n for each new line. The answer I posted does what I needed.

EDIT 3:
Yeah, I don't know why I didn't post the question with all the tweets to begin with. Guess I was just being lazy. Sorry guys for the chaos. And thank you all for trying to help. Again, if anyone has a better solution, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: @RichardScriven Please look at the Edit.

Comment: `gsub` will not accept a vector as an argument to 'replacement'. That is not valid R code you just put in your edit.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I know what you mean. It's just a warning which means it can't increment. I just realized I may not be able to do it using gsub in one shot. So, I wrote a for loop around the gsub and incremented it that way. Sorry for the trouble. I'll accept your answer if you have a better solution

Comment: It may be easier to work with JSON than regex.  e.g. if you load RJSONIO, jsonlite, or rjson, you can parse your text with `fromJSON(tst)`

Comment: Great @GSee, now I'm kinda wondering what we're doing because this string parses perfectly with `fromJSON` in `jsonlite` and I don't see any a's or b's, etc.

Comment: Sorry @RichardScriven to get you confused. The a's and b's was just an example to make it simple. The `\"n\":\"1\"}` at the end is what I wanted incremented; I added that later using gsub is what I was showing. The original text doesn't have `\"n\":\"1\"}`. I need this line added with the number 1 incremented for each line. Please see my answer

Comment: "incremented" is different than "appended"

Comment: @GSee, I agree, but see this is where it's really confusing. I need to append `n: ` with increment. I just edited the question, hope it's little clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confusing as your question is, the following will work for you.

```
paste0(sub('}$', ',\"n\":\"', tst), 1:length(tst), '\"}')
```

Comment: @RichardScriven yes, from the looks of it.

Comment: Would have been much better explained by saying "I want to append an element to my json text"

Comment: @RichardScriven, LOL. It probably would've been. This whole thing is so confusing for me. I'm doing map-reduce in R, and it completely threw me off. Besides, the thing that got me was that I did need to append, but also increment the value of appended n. Anyway, this works. so I'm gonna shut up, and read an English book, or probably will go take English as Second Language class yet again!!

Comment: @user1828605 - No worries.  I'm glad you got your problem solved after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Just apply over the list of integers that you want to append to the `gsub` replacement argument:

```
lapply(1:10, function(x) gsub("*}$", paste0(",\"n\":\"", x, "\"}"), tst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I just realized I could use for loop on each tweets.

This is what I did:

```
tweet.tst <- readLines("ows.json")
tweet.test <- character()

for(i in 1:length(tweet.tst)){
  tweet.test[i] <- gsub("*}$", paste0(",\"n\":\"",i,"\"}"), tweet.tst[i])
}
```

If anyone has a better solution, it's highly welcomed.

Comment: Why favour `for` over an `apply()`?

Comment: @GSee, LOL. The one is the original question with test.json was just a sample of tweets that I copied and created. After I had it working, I changed the file name to the original name. I know, it's funny though.LOL

Comment: The apply didn't sequentially increased the number. My output had n:10 on all lines. I initially accepted your response as answer, but after testing it, I realized it doesn't do what I need it to do.

Comment: I don't think you need a loop at all.  `paste` will paste by element.  For example `paste(letters[1:10], 1:10)`.  So if you remove the bad part first, then do `paste` on the next call, I think you'll be okay

Comment: You're not replacing `n:1`, you're adding another `n`.  Is that what you intended? (It doesn't seem like it from the Question)

Comment: @RichardScriven, could you please give me an example. The way I used paste didn't increment. Please see example in the original question.

Comment: @GSee, not exactly. Let me direct you to the original question where I gave you an example with a's and b's (which I confused RichardScriven :)). If you look at the output directly below the example in the question, you'll notice that the value of n is increasing for each line. I apologize if it's confusing. Whether it's a or b or whatever the new line is, the value of n needs to increase.

Comment: I'd like to, but honestly I don't really understand where you want to put `n:`.

Comment: No.  To use the "analogy" from the Question, the output you're ending up with is not `b, n:2`, but rather `b, n:1, n:2`

Comment: I know, I'm bad at that most of the times. But I try to explain as much as possible in the text, which apparently I'm doing really bad. Sorry guys for poor question and for confusing you all.

Comment: I think this is along the lines of what Richard had in mind: `paste0(sub("}$", "", tst), paste0(",\"n\":\"", seq_along(tst), "\"}"))`